# How do you call for the value of the clicked checkbox in an `*ngFor` loop?

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material, observable, subscribe

I'm trying to call the value of the "clicked" item for a  that is in an *ngFor loop. So far, this is my code:

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]='skillChoice'>
...

  <li *ngFor='let skill of skills'>
    <mat-checkbox
      [disabled]='enableSkill(skill)'
      [formControlName]='skill'
      (click)='onClick(skill)'
      >
       {{ skill }}
    </mat-checkbox>
  </li>
```

TS:

```
  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.skillChoice.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
             // val = {skill1: true, skill2: false, skill3:false...}
      ... //other various code
      let skillTracker = new Array()
        // skillTracker needs to be an array of recently clicked items, 
        // putting them in order of when they were clicked, not 
        // alphabetically.
           // i.e. skillTracker = [skill1, skill5, skill3] 
           //  if skill1 is clicked first, and skill3 is clicked last
    }
  }
...
  onClick(skill: string) {
    return skill
  }
```

In my research, I found that using `this.skillChoice.get("<insert skill name here>")` would read the boolean value of the skill. But that's not what I want. I want it to read and print the "skill" key of the `val` array. Is there a way to call the "event" of clicking within the `valueChanges.subscribe` without creating a `for` loop on  the skills in `val`?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a `FormArray` for `skillChoice`? It seems like that pattern would give you what you want.

Comment: I'm using a `FormGroup` and utilizing `FormBuilder`. And... I'm still a novice at using Angular and still learning to navigate all its functionalities. I'm going to go look into FormArray and see if it will work better instead of `FormGroup`.